# Use my 27" Thunderbolt monitor with a Macbook that has only DisplayPort output

Tags: macbook-pro, displayport, thunderbolt-display

Somehow this doesn't work out of the box – is there an adapter I can buy that will allow me to connect the Displayport output of my Macbook to the Thunderbolt input of my 27" Thunderbolt monitor?

Comment: No - time to sell something and replace it so as to have matching protocols.

Comment: To elaborate, a Thunderbolt output is backwards-compatible with a DisplayPort *input*, but not the other way around. As @bmike said, I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Apple's [Tech Specs for the Thunderbolt Display](http://www.apple.com/displays/specs.html) clearly state it requires a *Thunderbolt-enabled Mac computer, including MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, Mac mini, and iMac*

Comment: If Thunderbolt can output (into a DP display) the correct ("old") DisplayPort protocols, why can't it receive the "old" DisplayPort protocols.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @bmike, @djacobson, and @jaberg have stated in comments, that will not work. There is currently (as of March 2012) no adapter, nor do I expect there to be one to adapt mini-DisplayPort to Thunderbolt. (The standards were defined to be backward-compatible, not forward-compatible.)

Comment: BOOOO! This sucks ;)

Comment: The good news is that you can return it,  and if not that you can sell it, its still worth a lot. Additionally apple is still selling the 27" LED Cinema Display on the Apple Store, which will work on your Mac. Also note that DELL and HP are making a really nice professional IPS panel series of 27" LCD that offer the same 2560 by 1440 resolution, and those will work with you mac as well.

Comment: I thought Thunderbolt was DisplayPort with PCIe added in? http://www.intel.com/content/dam/staging/image/Kim/lightpeak-process-diagram_610x305.gif. So surely the DisplayPort protocols are the same?

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, Thunderbolt is DisplayPort multiplexed with PCIe such that a DisplayPort device will only read the DP signals. However, a Thunderbolt device would be expecting both signals and the absence of the PCIe part might cause it to think there is no signal at all.

Comment: @CajunLuke, it sounds like they could have quite easily made just DisplayPort work both ways. Someone could create an adapter which produces the PCIe and trick the display.

Answer (score 4):

No this will not work. Check the [system requirements](http://www.apple.com/displays/specs.html) for the Apple Thunderbolt display.

> System Requirements
>
> Thunderbolt-enabled Mac computer, including MacBook Air, MacBook Pro, Mac mini, and iMac
> OS X v10.6.8 or later

As of yet there is no way to add a Thunderbolt port to a Mac that did not ship with Thunderbolt.